# Counter doesn't start on time

Tags: c#

Ok, I'm trying to explain this on a simple example.
I want `counter` to have the value `0` at the beginning. `label1` is invisible until I click on `button1`. My problem now is that when I click on `button1` for the first time, 0 appears instead of 1. Meaning I need to click two times on `button1`, so that "1" appears. (I'm quite new to C#, so don't use jargon please =P)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Visible = false;
    }
    int counter = 0;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Visible = true;
        label1.Text = "number " + counter;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You exactly describe what your code does...you add `counter` (which is `0` as you know) to the string, so what did you expect? Maybe you wanted to do `counter++` **before** `label1.Text = "number " + counter;`?

Answer (score 3):

Look closely at your click method:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Visible = true;
    label1.Text = "number " + counter;
    counter++;
}
```

You are *first* assigning the (current) value of `counter` to `label1.Text` and *then* increment it. Swap statements 2 and 3:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Visible = true;
    counter++;
    label1.Text = "number " + counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either:

- Initialize counter to 1
- Increment the counter before showing it

  label1.Text = "number " + (++counter).ToString();

or

```
counter++;
label1.Text = "number " + counter.ToString();
```

- Use (counter+1) as your value

  label1.Text = "number " + (counter+1).ToString();